# PHP/Session/IE: Constant are saved, variable not

Tags: php, mysql, session, internet-explorer, variables

I have a very strange problem.
Situation: Session handling over MySQL, PHP 5.2.4, wildcard cookies, FF/Opera/Safari/Chrome works, IE7/8 not.

When I save a variable into the session, the value is lost. The DB shows after the write action only "N" instead of "123456".
Example:

```
$bar = 123456;
$_SESSION['foo'] = $bar;
```

But when I save a constant in the session, it works.

```
$_SESSION['foo'] = 123456;
```

This is not really a client problem, but only in IE it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

**Edit**:
This is the session write function:

```
function _write($id, $data) {

    $write = "UPDATE session SET time='".time()."', data='".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'";
    $result = @mysql_query($write);
    if(mysql_affected_rows()) return $result;
    else {
        $write = "INSERT INTO session (id, time, data) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."', '".time()."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data)."')";
        return @mysql_query($write);
    }
}
```

When I print the update query ($write) everything looks fine. I can execute the SQL manually and it works, also with variables.

Comment: Feels like the problem is how you're handling the sessions, not the values passed into session. Can you provide more context/ code?

Comment: The browser shouldn't normally matter, so something weird is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe sessionId in cookie every time is refreshing in IE?
SO every time - new session

Comment: For exmaple if the page is in iframe, there is a lot of problems with that